# What's the history of neutral density filters instead of aperture diaphragms in compact cameras?

Tags: aperture, optics, neutral-density, compact-cameras

Some compact cameras use [neutral density filters to control light](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/how-are-neutral-density-filters-in-compact-cameras-implemented) rather than aperture blades, to avoid the effects of diffraction in tiny sizes.

I first heard of this as a feature of the [Nokia N8](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/features/item/The_making_of_the_Nokia_N8s_camera.php) cameraphone, which emphasizes photography as a main selling point. But are there earlier cameras exhibiting this feature? How common is it? What other current models work this way?

---

<sub>This is a second question inspired by [this answer to an earlier question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/what-causes-outdoor-photos-to-turn-out-bright-white-when-taken-with-a-digital-cam/14732#14732).</sub>

Answer (score 10):

There are 98 *current* models in my database which are known to use an ND filter. I do not think enumerating them would serve much purpose. Some manufacturers do not specify if an ND filter is used or not, so there are probably more.

There are models of a variety of sizes but most are ultra-compacts, followed by ultra-zooms. Fuji and Casio have the most such models. Canon, Pentax and Sigma do not have any. Remaining manufacturers each have a few each.

Most models use single ND filter, either 3 stop or 2 stop. A few use two ND filters, which give then 4 options for letting light through (No ND, First ND, Second Filer, Both).

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. Is there a end-user-facing way to search on your site for this? What's the earliest one?

Comment: Nope, I had to query this manually. Not all parameters are exposed for various reasons. My database only goes back 6 years, so I've got the Fuji F480 as the earliest one but it probably goes back more.

Comment: Interesting. How do you find this stuff out? The [Fujifilm F480 press release](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0707/07072602fujifilmf480.asp#press) doesn't mention anything along those lines.

Comment: Press releases are frequently light on actual specifications, more so for some manufacturers. It takes a lot of digging and some things remain a mystery for a while. I remember recently emailing back and forth a major manufacturer just to find out the buffer-depth since the official specs said nothing and the manual said 'buffer depth varies'.

Comment: Yeah — thanks for doing the digging. (I've found the same thing in researching for my Pentax flash site.)