# How can I create light trails without a blurry subject?

Tags: night, shooting-technique

I would like to achieve this effect using my Nikon P510:

[image: example]

Are there any suggestions or tips that would help me do that?

Comment: Take a look at this excellent previous question on this topic: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/when-should-you-use-a-normal-flash-vs-a-second-curtain-flash

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on how the second photo looks, my guess is that it was extremely dark and that they took a flash photo with a bulb exposure and then tilted the camera upwards to create the trails from the only lights in the room (which would have been the audio gear).

This would leave the DJ well developed since he is only exposed during the flash and then expose the light trail from the gear over the top of the initial exposure.

Comment: I'm hairsplitting, but "turned the camera" sounds better than "moved the camera". The word "moving" sounds like "from eye-level to waist-level" or suchalike, at least to me, even though a tilt/turn/pan _is_ moving the camera just as well.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto - you're right, that is more clear.  Updated, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: any idea of the settings I should use?

Comment: @LuisValenciaMunoz - do you have a Bulb exposure setting, set the flash as necessary for a standard exposure using metering and then play with the length and speed of exposure.  The exact amount of light available is going to be a key distinction in achieving the effect and it's really impossible for me to give more detail without knowing too many factors that you are not going to be able to quantify here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be talking about the lines of light, they are commonly called **light trails**.  You can get that effect using a torch.  This [page](http://www.barnabyaldrick.com/blog/playing-with-light-photographic-experimentation-by-barnaby-aldrick/) has a nice looking example in medium sized room.

The basic way to get that is with a tripod and a long exposure.  This [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/why-are-these-light-trails-large-blobs-of-light-instead-of-nice-thin-lines) has some more tips on it.

Depending how long the exposure  is you will either see a dj with motion blur or they will be totally hidden, that will also depend on how much they are moving.

Edit: a comment made me realize that my example above is slightly misleading. It's better described with the more specific term **light painting**.

Comment: yes light trails like some pics here http://www.djresource.eu/Djsets/display/8199/

Comment: I think they must use a different method.  In the book The Complete Digital Photo Manual (Page 174, ISBN-10: 1847327400) they talked about creative use of flash while moving the camera or zooming out.  The examples on that page look sharp though, it could have been done in post-processing using Photoshop or some other image editor

Comment: amazing, I just played with the settings on that blog and I could make a single one, I guess I just have to find nice spots, these light trails are usually for cars, but for small areas with dj equipment and its own lights where the equipment doesnt move, I just have to press the button and move a little the camera to generate a trail

Comment: I'm not seeing an example of light painting on the blog. At least not in the way you described it.

Comment: JoanneC: I want to do this: http://youssefalfadl.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/zo.jpg

Comment: my nikon p501, has max exposure of 6 seconds, and F8.3

Comment: I cleaned up the original question to reflect the desired image, so feel free to adjust your response.

Comment: @LuisValenciaMunoz - Those Djresource.eu/Djsets example photos look like done by using zoom while in bulb-exposure. I did not know that is possible, but obviously it is.

Comment: @Esa With a DSLR lens with a physical zoom ring, there's nothing to stop you from zooming while exposing. Apparently this was kind of a visual fad for a while.