# Can I filter by autofocus in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, autofocus, manual-focus

Does Lightroom let me filter photos by whether they were manually focused? Or is this information not even stored in the ARW metadata? (I'm assuming they were not lost during DNG conversion in Lightroom.)

I often find that autofocus doesn't work for me in many situations ([Is it normal for autofocus to produce blurry photos under low light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/is-it-normal-for-autofocus-to-produce-blurry-photos-under-low-light/45956?noredirect=1#comment77119_45956)), so I'd like to filter my library (or create a Smart Collection) so that I can go through the auto-focused photos and verify that they were correctly focused. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The focus mode, if included in the EXIF information at all, is written in the *Maker Note* section that varies from one manufacturer to the next.

Since Adobe products such as CS/PS/LR ignore the *Maker Note* section of a file's EXIF information I highly doubt what you wish to do is possible using Adobe Lightroom.

For more information about how the focus information is saved in the EXIF data, see https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45622/15871

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checkout Jeffrey Friedl's lightroom plugin collection.  He has a few EXIF tools, including http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer and http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/metadata-viewer.

I haven't tried them yet, but the picture on metadata-viewer clearly shows it reveals "maker notes."

Comment: Is there something in those plugins that you believe will show the focus mode?

Comment: Yes, they state that they show the entire exif record, which would include the EXIF mode.

Comment: Oh, right: *if* your camera includes any EXIF data about focus mode then it will be accessible with those plugins.