# What is the difference between "color" and "tones"?

Tags: terminology, color, tone

I am working through the *Teach Yourself Photoshop* book. I opened up a NEF file in Adobe Camera Raw.

In the text it says:

> By shooting in raw you capture more information about the colors and
>   tones in a scene.

When looking at a histogram it mentions that from left to right you have the tonal range. I always thought that this tonal range represents all the colours in the photo, but the book now differentiates between colors and tones.

So my questions are what are colors and what are tones?

I hope someone can help me with my confusion.

Comment: Related to [What does “Tone” mean?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22311/what-does-tone-mean?rq=1)

Comment: This answer is all you need to know about *tone* in this context. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/22313/15871

Answer (score 12):

Using the term *tone* as an aspect of the hue and saturation of a *color*, along with its lightness or darkness is more applicable to some of the other visual arts, such as painting. Even there though, the most classic sense of the usage of *tonal value* refers to the lightness of a color independent of its *chromaticity*. Please see the link at the bottom of this answer for a very in depth look at the usage of *tone* in the context of painting.

In the context of photography, though, *tone* generally refers primarily to luminance or brightness. Since the terminology was developed when monochromatic photography was the overwhelming norm, the "tonal value" of an object referred to how bright or dark it appeared in relation to other objects in the scene. Ansel Adams' *Zone System* placed objects of varying brightness in 11 different zones along a *tonal scale* from totally black to pure white.

"Shifting an object's tonal value" involved placing a color filter over the lens to make objects that were the color of the filter brighter in the captured image than similarly bright objects in the actual scene that were a different color. (In actuality the filter reduces the overall amount of light allowed to pass through the lens, but after exposure is compensated for this light loss it has the effect of making like colored items brighter while other items are darkened). For instance, placing a red filter over the lens would make the blue sky appear darker while making a field of red flowers under that sky appear lighter in relation to the sky than would be the case without the filter. Using a green filter would darken the blue sky while keeping dark green foliage brighter.

At the same time that photography was still primarily a B&W activity, others were researching and developing theories of human perception of color and models that could be used to describe the colors that humans perceive. Albert Munsell did exhaustive research in the decade between 1900 and 1910 and developed his color model which expresses color based on value (brightness, or tone), chroma (saturation), and hue (color).

[image]

The book you are studying uses the word "tones" in this way. The histogram shows a distribution of the various brightness level in a photo. The darkest tones are represented on the left, the brightest tones are represented on the right. When you see phrases such as *tonal value*, *tonal range*, *tonal scale*, etc. they are almost certainly referring to luminance, or brightness, when used in the context of photography.

If you see the phrase *color tones*, on the other hand, it usually refers to the hue and saturation of an object as well as its brightness. Since the book you are reading seems to keep the meaning of *color* distinct from the meaning of *tones*, it doesn't appear your book uses the term *color tones* in this way.

*Color* refers to to the various hues created by the mixture of varying levels of red, green, and blue present in the photo. Red, green, and blue are the colors that cameras measure. Purple is a mix of red and blue. Orange is a mix of green and red with more red than green. Yellow is a mix of green and red with more green than red. All of the colors in the color space with which our cameras and monitors are capable of capturing and displaying are various combinations of red, green, and blue.

Here's an [in-depth article](http://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/color11.html) that discusses the concepts of *color* and *tone* in the context of selecting pigments for creating a painting. Even there references to *tone* generally refer to luminance.

> Tonal value
>
> Lightness, which artists traditionally refer to as value or tonal
>   value, is the light or dark of a color independent of its chromaticity
>   (hue and chroma).
>
> Given all the space devoted to hue in color theory, it is surprising
>   to learn that value is the most important design element of a
>   painting. It is hard to overstate the importance of good value
>   structure to the impact of visual art.

Comment: Hmmm. I think @Octopus's answer clearly contradicts your thesis. The color picture shown there has one bar for value, and another two-dimensional box showing _both_ saturation and value. There's no label, but I think it's perfectly reasonable to call that box "tones".

Comment: Adams, of course, was primarily working in black and white, making his use of the term somewhat specialized. Without colorfulness, tone _is_ just value.

Comment: One can use a word however one wishes. In photography the historical usage of *tone* primarily refers to luminance value. Even in the context of color photography, the usage of *tone* apart from the word *color* has been primarily about luminance. Octopus's answer also points out that HSV divides saturation and value into two separate components. In his chart the horizontal dimension is saturation, the vertical dimension is the tonal value.

Comment: So, under this definition, shouldn't the book have said "colors, tones, and saturations"? I'm not really convinced.

Comment: *Hue* and *saturation* are components that *always* fall under the larger category of *color*. *Tone*, when properly used in the context of photography, is a category that refers to luminance, whether B&W or color is the medium. Just because some folks misuse a word doesn't validate that usage when there is a preponderance of prior usage that indicates otherwise.

Comment: Further, the question above makes it a given that the book the OP is trying to understand separates the meaning of *color* from the meaning of *tone*. In that context I think your answer just adds confusion by arguing that the *tone* can be the same thing as *saturation*. The question is pretty clear that the book referenced makes *color* and *tone* two distinct terms. Your answer argues that it's really one term: *Color & tones*.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the word is not sometimes used in photography to *just* mean value. I think that's largely due to photography's history as a black and white medium, combined today with the inherent sloppiness of English. And I agree that it doesn't mean saturation alone — I never said it did. However, it *does* mean both value and saturation together. Otherwise, if tone is just a synonym for value in the context quoted (and similar ones), the phrase would be missing the whole aspect of saturation or colorfulness, and it clearly doesn't have that intention.

Comment: Your link and quote do not support your argument, because it very carefully uses the term "tonal value" rather than just using "tone" alone, and then uses "value" for most of the conversation. Again, yes, value is a key aspect of tone.

Comment: *Tonal value* is an ubiquitous phrase that has long been present in the literature of photography and art. Where are the references to *tonal saturation*? Nowhere until anyone with a keyboard can write whatever they want to and post it on the internet.

Answer (score 9):

Traditionally in art, there are several different words used to talk about what we might less precisely all refer to as "color". They are:

- **Hue**: this is the property that means the color itself, regardless of how bright, dark, or pure it is. Blue, orange, red, green, purple, yellow — these are hues. This is the position on a color wheel, basically. (Including all the infinity between the primaries and secondaries.)
- **Colorfulness**: This is the impression of whether something appears to be more or less colorful (as opposed to gray). This is closely related to **saturation**, which is how colorful something appears for its brightness. (Hue and colorfulness together make up the more technical term **chromaticity**.)
- **Value**: And this is simply the brightness. (In more technical use, you may also see **luminance** and **luma**, which are other ways of referring to *basically* the same thing, but with different math behind it.)
- **Tint**, **shade**, and **tone**: The first two of these come directly from mixing paint: add white to a color to make a tint, or black to make a shade. Collectively, "tone" is the range of possibilities mixed with any amount of white, gray, or black. **"Tone" is a way of referring to both value and colorfulness/saturation together.** In other contexts, though (because language is often messy), people may use it to just mean brightness/value.

When someone talks in general about **colors and tones** as in your quote, generally what they mean is: *collectively, all of this*. The phrase refers to all the possibilities of adjustment — both hue *and* colorfulness and brightness, rather than *just* the brightness or *just* the position on the color wheel.

Comment: The opening paragraph of this article totally contradicts your position, even in the context of selecting materials for creating a painting.    http://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/color11.html#valchrom

Comment: The question above makes it a given that the book the OP is trying to understand makes a distinction between the meaning of *color* from the meaning of *tone*. In that context I think your answer just adds confusion by arguing that *tone* can also be the same thing as *saturation*. The question is pretty clear that the book referenced makes *color* and *tone* two distinct terms. Your answer argues that it's really one term: *Color & tones*.

Comment: You are really confusingly putting words into my mouth. I do not say at all that "tone can be the same thing as saturation". I think that's already clear but I'll reword to make it more so.

Comment: And I also don't understand where you think I'm saying it is "one term", except maybe that I put both in bold together in the paragraph where I explain that when both terms are used together they are meant to be comprehensive of all possibilities — which includes different saturations, even though you for some reason want it not to.

Comment: Clarification: I think your answer certainly argues that *tone* can mean *value + saturation*.

Comment: And you are arguing that the phrase asked about means to exclude saturation?

Comment: If the only reference to *colors and tones* in the text referenced in the OP was the one quoted you might have an argument there. But the question above goes on to make clear that the text uses the term *tones* and the term *colors* in two very distinct ways.

Comment: In my interpretation, *saturation* and *hue* are both components of the word *color* as used in that sentence. *Tone* is not.

Comment: Here is my interpretation of the two words as used in the quote from the book included in the question above: "By shooting in raw you capture more information about the colors (*saturation and hue*) and tones (*luminance levels*) in a scene."

Answer (score 3):

My explanation includes a graphic to hopefully help make it clearer.

The bar on the right is the hues. The square to the left contains all of the *tones* of a particular hue. Any particular *tone* is described with two dimensions, the vertical dimension (in this representation), sometimes referred to as *brightness* or *value* and the horizontal dimension, also known as *saturation*.

*Brightness* and *value* can sometimes be technically different as well depending on context, but they are very similar terms.

The triad we are looking at here are often referred to as *hue*, *saturation* and *value* (or HSV). Or as it relates to your question, *color* and *tone*.

[image]

"When looking at a histogram it mentions that from left to right you have the tonal range."

The *tonal range* in that statement is really only referring to the rightmost vertical slice of our tone square above, so really just the fully saturated brightness. When you consider that one slice from each of the three additive primary colors; red, green and blue; you can make up all of the colored pixels in any image.

Comment: To tie this to my answer a bit, although it doesn't usually come up in photographic use, one can think of the top horizontal edge of the "tones" box as the _tints_ (the hue mixed with white) and the right vertical edge as the _shades_ (the hue mixed with black).

Comment: One could argue that the components in HSV could also be labeled color, saturation, and tone. Saturation in the large box is along the horizontal axis, tone is along the vertical axis.