# How to do Low Key Photography with Sony A57 Camera?

Tags: flash, portrait, studio-lighting, low-key

I have a Sony A57 and a Sony HVL-43 flash. I have been trying low key photography wirelessly, but I am struggling with the settings. I've followed settings from other sources I have found, and I have had a play with a lot of others, and I have also used a softbox, but it was still too light. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post what you _have_ tried? An example photo that you're not satisfied with would be ideal.

Comment: Also, note that there's an ambiguity between low key lighting (as from cinema) and a low key image (as traditional in photography and the visual arts). (See [this question and answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/10300/1943) for details.) Since the actual effect (and the way to get there) can be very different, Which do you mean?

Comment: BTW: Your question is unrelated to Sony - you just happen to use Sony flashes, but the issue you have isn't related to the equipment. And, yes: we really do need to know what did you try. Perhaps you can show us a sample picture on what you think is a failed attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

First, and my preference, would be to expose properly and adjust via post-processing on a computer. You have much easier control of how and where light is shown to highlight your subject.

Alternatively, shoot everything in manual. Set your flash to a constant power (start at 1/4 or 1/8 power) Keep you shutter speed to the maximum sync speed (1/200 or 1/250) to minimize ambient light, and then adjust your aperture as needed to let in more/less light. You could also adjust your flash power as needed.

When in manual, change one setting at a time and see what effect it has; best way to learn how to use off camera flashes.