# How does one create this vintage look?

Tags: photo-editing, effect, vintage

What program would I need or manual adjustments in order to create a photo like this? What is this filter called? I typically use Aperture as my editing program but would be open to using others.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a vintage/dreamy look?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39431/how-to-get-a-vintage-dreamy-look)

Comment: Use film and leave it on the dashboard of your car for a whole summer in Phoenix.

Answer (score 4):

I can hint you:

- Reduce contrast and saturation
- Apply a blue tint
- Add noise
- Add vignetting

Answer (score 2):

There is no single way to produce an "effect", as there are *many* ways to produce effects very similar to the one you're referencing.  The first step would be to properly expose the photo in order to facilitate the rest of the edits.  What I mean by that is the photo has blown out white areas and what could be image noise.  In order to create those two effects one would:

- Expose for the darker parts and increase the ISO instead of slowing
  the shutter speed.  This will help produce the noise you see - but
  may not always work.  Alternately you can expose for the bright white
  pages, keep a low ISO and increase the shutter speed.
- Now that you have the proper exposure and noise, you alter the
  exposure in Aperture.  Adjust the exposure to blow out the white
  area's details and expose the rest of the image to the desired level,
  which brings out the noise that was likely not visible until now.

As has already been noted, some of the other obvious basic adjustments would be to:

- reduce the contrast
- adjust the color curves (notably the blue is stronger in your
  reference, so is the red)
- OR manipulate the saturation instead of color curves for specific
  color channels to increase the blues and reds
- add a vignette using Aperture's vignette tool

There are also Photoshop actions or presets in other programs, apps that give effects, layers, filters, etc., but this is as close as I can imagine doing it with just Aperture.

Answer (score -1):

like I know, there are many way can achieve this look, try search "lomo effect" on youtube

Comment: Would be better if you could answer with some information rather than suggesting they search elsewhere.