# Can you help identify this common style of photo editing, it's like a faded style?

Tags: photo-editing

These 2 photos below have a similar editing style, which I'm trying to identify. They're all like faded out and slightly bland/muted in colour, which I really like.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is one of our most frequent questions, in slight variants.

Comment: See also [How can this brightly colored yet gentle pastel-color effect be achieved?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46592/how-can-this-brightly-colored-yet-gentle-pastel-color-effect-be-achieved/)

Comment: See also [How to get a vintage/dreamy look?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39431/how-to-get-a-vintage-dreamy-look)